# Symfony 404 errors

Tags: php, mysql, symfony1, doctrine

On my local machine, the symfony project I have created works perfectly.

I have installed symfony on my testing server and it is working fine. When I go to the URL in the browser I get the "Symfony Project Created" page. I ran the check_configuration.php and everything checks out.

The problem I am having is: I have created my database and uploaded the table data. I have uploaded the files from my local machine to the server with FTP. When I try to access the module I created, it throws a 404 Error:

Not Found

```
The requested URL /mymodule was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

Here's some examples:

On my local machine using MAMP, I use the following URL that works fine:

```
http://localhost:8080/frontend_dev.php/mymodule
```

After I have uploaded everything, if I go to the testing server URL:

```
http://my.url.com:8090/
```

I get the "Project Success" page with the /sf images and styles.

**BUT** If I try

```
http://my.url.com:8090/mymodule
```

I get the 404 error as if the page does not exist, which makes me thik smfony does not know about the frontend module.

Any Help?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You'll need to do two things:

1) Ensure that mod_rewrite is enabled in Apache.

2) Double-check the `.htaccess` file in the document root to make sure it is pointing to your `app.php`. Something along the lines of:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Thanks. I did not try the most obvious url. I typed in http://my.url.com:8090/index.php/mymodule and it worked! Now I have an Internal Server Error, but hey... its progress.

Answer (score 3):

I used to have this problem too, please take a look at my configurations and try them out

inside my .htaccess:

Hi all, I have been having this problem too.  And it seems that the "stock" .htaccess is the problem.  I have solved this in my environment and here is my .htaccess with notes:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)/(.*)::\2$
    RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]
    RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
    RewriteRule ^app_dev.php(/(.*)|$) %{ENV:BASE}/$2 [R=301,L]    ##### this is the part that you should tweak, have the .htaccess point the request to app_dev.php, since the routing.yml is empty initially
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
    RewriteRule .? - [L]
    RewriteRule .? %{ENV:BASE}/app_dev.php [L]        ##### this is the part that you should tweak, have the .htaccess point the request to app_dev.php, since the routing.yml is empty initially
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_alias.c>
        # When mod_rewrite is not available, we instruct a temporary redirect of
        # the startpage to the front controller explicitly so that the website
        # and the generated links can still be used.
        RedirectMatch 302 ^/$ /app.php/
        # RedirectTemp cannot be used instead
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

inside my "symfony" entry in /etc/apache2/sites-available:

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.1.15>
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
ServerName symfony
DocumentRoot /var/www/Symfony/web
DirectoryIndex app.php
<Directory /var/www/Symfony/web>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
# Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
# alert, emerg.
LogLevel warn
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```